# Database Design Assistance

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, database-design

Making a quality checklist in which an employee would sign, using their employee number. The employee would supply their employee number in text-box beside each item they need to check. The Items are grouped in sections, and sections grouped in a Product, and a unit which is 1 singular product that is manufactured.

So far I Have:

Unit (Id, Name, startdate, serialnumber, ProductType)

ProductType (Id, Name)

Sections (Id, Name, ProductTypeId*) 
items (Id, Name, SectionId, EmpNumber*)

My issue is, I would like a section to be able to belong to many ProductTypes and need a way to include employee numbers to the items. Will I need some sort of Junction Table? For what it is worth it will be made code-first asp.net core.

The checklist when displayed would look something like this:

Product: Product One 
Date: 05/27/2020
Serial #:5656ASF

```
Section One
    Item One | EmpNumber
    Item Two | EmpNumber
    Item Three | EmpNumber

Section Two
    Item One  | EmpNumber
    Item Two  | EmpNumber

Section Three
    Item One | EmpNumber
```

.....

Thanks in advance!

***** UPDATE ****

I did some more work to it and this is what i got:

Unit (Id, SerialNumber, StartDate, Model_Id)
ProductType (Id, Name)

Model (Id, Name, ProductType_Id)

ModelSection (Model_Id, Section_Id)

Section (Id, Name)

SectionItem(Section_Id, Item_Id)

Item (Id, Name)

BuyOff (Id, Unit_Id, Item_Id, EmployeeNumber)

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat but to make a proper decision you really need to look at the bigger picture of what you are trying to accomplish.

One way would be to use link tables, which I suspect is what you mean when you say Junction Tables.

An example could look like this:

Unit - ID, Name, StartDate, ProductTypeID
ProductType - ID, Name
Section- ID, Name
Item - ID, Name

---

SectionProductTypeLink - (unique ID maybe), SectionID, ProductTypeID
SectionEmployeeLink - (unique ID maybe), SectionID, EmployeeNumber

You could add an ID field to these link tables which would be an auto-generated primary key so you can have as many links as you want. You might need some unique indexes to make sure you can't add the same link multiple times.

It all depends however on how you are going to use this data as ultimately this will dictate what the structure of the database will be.

I'd say choose one way of doing it, then start writing the SQL required to get the data you need, in any format you need. If the structure holds then you can proceed to worrying about UI stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added an updated version to the original post.